# Android : service and socket connection

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application (I'm a newbie) and I am trying to open a socket and check the connection status when launching the app.

To do so, I have a MainActivity that starts and binds to a service. On the onBind() method of this service, I call a function openSocket() that tries to open a socket with given IP address and port. To make this connection, I use an AsyncTask where I try and catch exceptions on opening the socket in doInBackground() and I update a boolean according to the connection status in onPostExecute().

In MainActivity, I want to retrieve this boolean value (Service.getConnectionStatus()).

The problem is that Service.getConnectionStatus() gets called in MainActivity before onPostExecute(), resulting in the boolean value not being correctly updated.

I have been doing research for a few days now, trying many different things and now I'm quite confused... Would anyone have an idea how to wait for onPostExecute() to finish before calling getConnectionStatus in MainActivity ?

I've tried to set a Listener for AsyncTask, but the result is the same. I've also tried to call openSocket() from different methods but without success...

Thank you for your help.

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mIBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private Socket mSocket;
    private String mDstAddress = "192.168.0.222";
    private int mDstPort = 23;
    private Boolean mConnectionStatus = false;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        openSocket(mDstAddress, mDstPort);
        return mIBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public int getConnectionStatus() {
        if (mConnectionStatus) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void closeSocket() {
        if (mSocket != null) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
        }
        mSocket = null;
    }

    public void openSocket(String dstAddress, int portAddress) {
        mDstAddress = dstAddress;
        mDstPort = portAddress;
        ConnectSocket connect =
            new ConnectSocket(mDstAddress, mDstPort);
        connect.execute();
    }


public class ConnectSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";

    ConnectSocket(String addr, int port) {
        dstPort = port;
        dstAddress = addr;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                mSocket = new Socket(mDstAddress, mDstPort);
                mConnectionStatus = true;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                mConnectionStatus = false;
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
                e.printStackTrace();
                closeSocket();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                mConnectionStatus = false;
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
                e.printStackTrace();
                closeSocket();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (response.contains("Exception")) {
                mConnectionStatus = false;
            } else {
                mConnectionStatus = true;
            }
            this.cancel(true);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java (onServiceConnected only) :**

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mIsBound = true;
        int statusResult = mService.getConnectionStatus();
        Log.i(TAG, "statusResult: " + Integer.toString(statusResult));
        mDisplayNumber.setText(Integer.toString(statusResult));
        if (statusResult == 0) {
            createDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to do it the opposite way; have the service notify the activity when it is done. See the linked post for how to do that

Comment: Thank you so much ! Looks like it's the SO post I was hopelessly looking for ahahah.